# To change the value of the URL in the browser, but not the React component to be rendered

Tags: react-router

I have a link   `<Link to = "country/USA"/>`

Then the route   `<Route path="country/:countryId" component={Country}/>`

When the component "**Country**" is rendered, the browser Url is

```
http://<domain>/country/USA
```

Is there a way to change the display of the browser Url as `http://<domain>/country`, and have the "**countryId**" only as the Route props in the **Country** component.

Have gone through

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Couldn't find anything helpful.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're okay with `USA` being part of a query string, there's nothing much you can do within React Router (snippet comes from react-training site)

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/courses',
  search: '?sort=name',
  hash: '#the-hash',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}}/>
```

Another alternative that doesn't involve router is to have a Container component that receives `USA` as props and then programatically render the component that you want. I'd say that's way too much work for something that makes sense to be shown in the URL

**EDITED**

One way to do it via component would be something like this:

```
<Route path="country/some-static-keyword" render={() => <Country countryId={this.props.countryId}/>}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @tan-kim-loong.

Comment: But its the project requirement, not to show any specific details of the Item in the browser Url. So basically what I need this to Route to the Component, but not have the specific details(**countryId**) in the browser Url.